# Firefox and IE rendering same image differently!

Tags: internet-explorer, image, firefox, rendering

This is an exact duplicate of: [IE6 issues with transparent PNGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130161/ie6-issues-with-transparent-pngs)

---

Firefox:[image]

IE 6:[image]
The background for the image is transparent. Yet IE seems to screw it up. Any ideas?

Comment: IE6 and Firefox rendering differently?  Stop the presses!

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130161/ie6-issues-with-transparent-pngs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130161/ie6-issues-with-transparent-pngs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE6 does not render transparent PNGs properly. There's a javascript fix, or [some such](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6), but it's easier if you just don't use PNGs.

Answer (score 2):

Undoubtedly a PNG.  IE6 doesn't handle PNG alpha transparency natively, though there are some hacks that work.  Here's [one](http://bjorkoy.com/past/2007/4/8/the_easiest_way_to_png/).  Here's [another](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think IE completely fixed PNGs until IE8.

IE6 had transparency issues

IE7 had color pallet issues

If you need a transparent image and you need it to work on IE6, use a GIF. They render properly on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use PNGs in IE6, just not 24bit PNGs, because the alpha channels get turned to blocks of grey. You can use Javascript to solve this issue, but it doesn't work in all cases (such as a repeating background). Check out this link: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/